# How do I find the numpy.amax from the second list of a multidimensional list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have 'n' series of lists that I send to a plotting routine. The second element in each list are frequency breakpoints for use in plotting the x axis. I need to go through each of the 'n' series, and figure out what is the absolute lowest frequency breakpoint, and wat is the absolute highest frequency breakpoint for establishing my X axis boundary on the plot.

Each list consists of an arbitrary number of lists: ['sensor description',[frequency breakpoints],[amplitudes at those breakpoints]]
i.e.: [['sensor_A',[0.1,1.0,10.0],[1.5,15.0,150.0]],['sensor_B',[0.05,1.0,20.0],[0.5,15.0,300.0]]]

I thought I could do it directly with numpy.amax and numpy.amin but haven't hit upon the right combination...  Do I have to iterate through the whole list one element at a time or can I use a [:] to get the amax , amin functions to do it for me?

Haven't found any better solutions but it seems there's got to be a faster way.

```
pc = [['sensor_A',[0.05,1.0,10.0],[1.5,15.0,150.0]],['sensor_B',[0.2,1.0,20.0],[0.5,15.0,300.0]]]
# I want the nmax of the second list from each of the lists, which should be 20
# I want the nmin of the second list from each of the lists, which should be 0.05
print(np.amax(pc[1][1])) # unfortunately this only looks at the second list 
print(np.amin(pc[1][1])) # and ignores the first.

max=0       # This works but seems kind of clunky. Is there a shorter solution?
min=1.0E+6
for p in pc:
    if (np.amax(p[1]) > max):
        max = np.amax(p[1])
    if (np.amin(p[1]) < min):
        min = np.amin(p[1])
print( min,max )
```

Comment: In your code you're only checking the second sublist for the max/min values, what about the last ones? You just want the first?

Comment: Correct, I only want the second sublist in each list. The second sublist represents frequency, in Hz and is used for the X axis on a plot. The third sublist is the associated amplitude point that is matched to the frequency and is used for the Y axis for the plot. If I have a bunch of sensors, some of them will plot over longer frequency bands than others. I want to figure out the lowest and highest frequencies in my dataset. The iteration (for p in pc:) works but seems clunky.

Comment: `max` is a builtin python function. It is not advisable and very frowned upon to overwrite it with your own variable.

Comment: Duly noted, I will correct that in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `numpy` for this since your input list is not a numpy array.. You'll have to use the builtin `min` and `max` functions.

```py
pc = [['sensor_A',[0.05,1.0,10.0],[1.5,15.0,150.0]],['sensor_B',[0.2,1.0,20.0],[0.5,15.0,300.0]]]

# the builtin max function can accept a key to use when determining the max.
# Since you want the max from the 2nd list in each element in pc, we can use
max_item = max(pc, key = lambda i: max(i[1]))

# The lambda creates an anonymous function that takes in one argument, i,
# which is each outer list in pc and then uses the maximum of the 2nd element 
# (which is your freq breakpoints) to determine the final maximum. The output
# will be an outer-list from pc.

print(max_item)
# outputs: >> ['sensor_B', [0.2, 1.0, 20.0], [0.5, 15.0, 300.0]]
# We get the right output, we know 20 is the max freq breakpoint from our eyes...

# Now we have the element in pc that has the max freq breakpoint, pull out the max
xmax = max(max_item[1])
# max_item[1] is the list of freq breakpoints, and we just take the max from that.

# It can be confusing with so many max's, so let's put it all together on one line.
xmax_oneline = max(max(pc, key = lambda i: max(i[1]))[1])
print(xmax_oneline)
# Outputs: >> 20.0 as desired.

# We can do similar to find the minimum
xmin_oneline = min(min(pc, key = lambda i: min(i[1]))[1])
print(xmin_oneline)
# Outputs: >> 0.05 as desired.
```